# Sort Table rows by .class on page load jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table cell within my HTML table which contains information - amongst that information is a price (class .amount). I want to sort the table rows by that class using jQuery when the page loads.

Example.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>info info html <span class="amount">10</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>info info html <span class="amount">40</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>info info html <span class="amount">30</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>info info html <span class="amount">16</span></td>
</tr>

etc
```

I do not require client side table sorting. I just want the table to be pre-arranged for the user so I would like not to use a library.

if you would like to see the page in question please use a popular mobile useragent and visit http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-a3-black-deals/ under contracts tab.

Comment: I don't see id="amount" anywhere

Comment: sorry I meant to say class

Comment: is there any way you can provide a Live code like codepen or other?

Comment: it's just a basic html table 4 colums about 30 rows

Comment: _"I want to sort the table rows by that class"_ Sort by what variable ? What is expected result ?  _"I just want the table to be pre-arranged for the user so I would like not to use a library"_ What is purpose of including `jquery` tag ?

Comment: I can link to the site but you would have to change your useragent to view the mobile version in question

Comment: @guest271314 i have no idea what your talking about jquery tag?? I want to sort the table by the variable .class amount

Comment: I meant a library other than jquery

Comment: _"I want to sort the table by the variable .class amount"_ `html` at Question contains one `.amount` element . Sort how ? What is expected result ?

Comment: That is just one cell from the table I will update the snippet

Comment: @Scott Can you describe how the sort should be performed ? Should greatest number be first ? Should least number be last ?

Comment: @guest271314 ascending price low to high

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108234/discussion-between-guest271314-and-scott).

Comment: updated code example

Comment: " I want to sort the table rows by that class using jQuery when the page loads" and "I do not require client side table sorting. I just want the table to be pre-arranged for the user so I would like not to use a library." are contradictory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through all rows and get the values in the amount field, then sort the array and replace all the rows in the new order:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var dataRows = [];

  //Create an array of all rows with its value (this assumes that the amount is always a number.  You should add error checking!!  Also assumes that all rows are data rows, and that there are no header rows.  Adjust selector appropriately.
  $('tr').each(function(i,j) {
    dataRows.push({'amount': parseFloat($(this).find('.amount').text().replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, '')), 'row': $(this)});
  })

  //Sort the data smallest to largest
  dataRows.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.amount - b.amount;
  });

  //Remove existing table rows.  This assumes that everything should be deleted, adjust selector if needed :).
  $('table').empty();

  //Add rows back to table in the correct order.
  dataRows.forEach(function(ele) {
    $('table').append(ele.row);
  })
})
```

Comment: This works perfectly but it wont sort the data when there is a leading currency symbol. I was wondering if you could help me modify it to work with a leading (£) sign https://jsfiddle.net/ghzch66e/12/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439250/jquery-on-page-load-sorting-will-not-sort-with-leading-currency-symbol

Comment: I updated the example to remove non-numeric characters: http://codepen.io/nobrien/pen/eZevgd

Answer (score -1):

One more solution. Replace the index `comparer(3)` here to sort by other columns. (**Note**: 0 based index)

```js
var table =  $('table');   
var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer(3)) ;     
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  table.append(rows[i])
}

function comparer(index) {  
  return function(a, b) {      
    var valA = getCellValue(a, index),
      valB = getCellValue(b, index);    
    return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ?  valA - valB  : valA.localeCompare(valB)  
  }
}

function getCellValue(row, index) {
  return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>info info html <span class="amount">10</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>info info html <span class="amount">40</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>info info html <span class="amount">30</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>info info html <span class="amount">16</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```